# How to perform object visibility test on Android OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, visibility

I have a world full of 2D squares (z=0). At startup I setup projection in such a way that the whole world is visible on the screen, using:

```
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(left, right, bottom, top, zNear, zFar);
```

Then I allow the user to zoom in the world with fingers by using:

```
gl.glScalef(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, 1.0f);
```

I want to make visibility test for objects that appear not visible as the user is zooming in to not render them (performance boost).
I found this method:

```
android.opengl.Visibility.visibilityTest(float[] ws, int wsOffset, float[] positions, int positionsOffset, char[] indices, int indicesOffset, int indexCount);
```

But I can't make it work, nor I found ANY examples of the usage of this method on Internet. Currently this method returns result=0 for every square I test, even when scaling is not applied (mScaleFactor = 1.0)

The way I'm doing this:

```
    final short SQUARE_VERTICES_ORDER_TEMPLATE[] = {0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3};
    .....
    float[] vertices = toArray(mVertexBuffer);
    short[] indices = toArray(mIndicesBuffer);
    char[] charIndices = new char[indices.length];

    // method needs char[]
    for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; i++) {
        short shortIndex = indices[i];
        charIndices[i] = (char) shortIndex;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < mSquares.size(); i++) {
        int numIndicesPerSquare = SQUARE_VERTICES_ORDER_TEMPLATE.length;
        int indicesOffset = i * numIndicesPerSquare;
        int result = Visibility.visibilityTest(matrixGrabber.mProjection, 0, vertices, 0, charIndices, indicesOffset, numIndicesPerSquare);
        switch (result) {
            case 0:
                Log.v(TAG, "Object NOT VISIBLE: " + mSquares.get(i)); // hits every time
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.v(TAG, "Object PARTIALLY VISIBLE: " + mSquares.get(i));
                break;
            default:
                TAG.toString(); // to place a break point
                break;
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm picking up the right Matrix required by this method.
Could you please validate the right usage of this method or give any other tips or workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what is wrong, visibilityTest method requires multiplied matrix. Here is how it should be:

```
matrixGrabber.getCurrentState(gl);

float[] resultMatrix = new float[matrixGrabber.mProjection.length];
Matrix.multiplyMM(resultMatrix, 0, matrixGrabber.mProjection, 0, matrixGrabber.mModelView, 0);
....
Visibility.visibilityTest(resultMatrix, 0, vertices, 0, charIndices, indicesOffset, numIndicesPerSquare);
```